# Xamarin Microcharts extension namespace not recognised

Tags: xml, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently building an app in Xamarin forms. I am trying to get a simple chart element to appear on a page when loaded.

I have installed the `Microcharts.Forms v0.6.2`  package by Aloïs Deniel to use in my Xamarin forms application.

When I add the line `<forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1"/>` into my `LiteChartPage.xaml` file, on compile I get this error.

`'forms' is an undeclared prefix. Line 8, position 6.`

I have `using Microcharts;` in my `LiteChartPage.xaml.cs` file.

here is my xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Forms;assembly=Microcharts.Forms"
             x:Class="App1.LiteChartPage">
        <forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the `LiteChartPage.xaml.cs` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using static SkiaSharp.SKCanvas;
using Microcharts;
using Entry = Microcharts.Entry;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class LiteChartPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LiteChartPage()
        {
            Microcharts.Chart c = new Microcharts.BarChart();
            List<Microcharts.Entry> entries = new List<Microcharts.Entry>
            {
                new Microcharts.Entry(200)
                {
                    Color = SkiaSharp.SKColor.Parse("#FF1493"),
                    Label = "Litecoin Price",
                    ValueLabel = "200"
                },
                new Microcharts.Entry(400)
                {
                    Color = SkiaSharp.SKColor.Parse("#BB1493"),
                    Label = "Bitcoin Price",
                    ValueLabel = "200"
                },
                new Microcharts.Entry(-100)
                {
                    Color = SkiaSharp.SKColor.Parse("#FFBBD3"),
                    Label = "Etherium Price",
                    ValueLabel = "200"
                },
            };
            c.Entries = entries;      
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to add some reference to the forms namespace somewhere?

Comment: You are missing prefix declaration for 'forms' - try using   <chart:ChartView.. />

Comment: The error changes to forms with a capital F

```Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Microcharts' (are you missing an assembly reference?```

Comment: In case you missed it, I believe you will need to install [Microcharts.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microcharts.Forms/) nuget package as well in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the prefix of  to .because here you declared the namespace in the content page as chart but using forms.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your namespace as:

```
xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Forms;assembly=Microcharts.Forms"
```

That means in your XAML you should use the define NS **chart** rather than **forms**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you installed MicroCharts nugget so your problem may be you using .NET standard 2.0 and the nugget has no support for it. To get away from this problem you should install latest pre-release of this nugget. It supports .NET standard 2.0